# Convert Varchar to Datetime format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a column named `[open]` (`varchar(MAX)`) to `datetime`.
I am using this code:

```
select cast([open] as datetime) as [open_time] 
from [dbo].[museum_hours]
```

But I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The `[open]` column is in the format `hh:mm:AM/PM`, such as `'10:30:AM'`.

Comment: what is the content of that column

Comment: The [open] (varchar(max), null) column is in this 10:30:AM format

Comment: If that is an example of your sample data then why is the error a surprise? It's not a vaid *datetime* nor even a valid *time*

Comment: that is no valid  date form,at you need to process that first

Comment: Remove the : before the AM

Comment: Just an aside... try_convert()/try_cast() would return a NULL if the conversion fails.

Comment: I get the data from kaggle. following a tutorial from youtube. He can convert that using to_timestamp(open,'HH:MI AM') postgresql. but I do not know how to do it in sql server

Comment: Why are you storing a *time* value in a column that you've explicitly stated it likely to be longer than 8,000 characters? What *"time"* (accurate to a minute) is longer than *five* characters, let alone **8,000**? Fix your design, store your *time* as a **`time`**.

Comment: This is where you look at the various strung and date time functions available in SQL server and using then to create the format you need. That said a similar question has been asked many times before.

Comment: To help you out on the assumption your string data is a consistent format you can try `select Cast(Stuff([open], 6, 1, ' ') as time)`

Comment: This dataset? https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thedevastator/paintings-collection?select=museum_hours - You need to do some string manipulation to get that into a format SQL Server can cast to `time`. There is no method where you can tell it to expect a particular arbitrary format string

Comment: yeah, this one. but it is kinda easier with postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

- "10:30:am" is an invalid time format, the second colon needs to be removed. This can be done using [stuff()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)
- A datetime data type **requires** a date (time of day is optional, but the default date is 1900-01-01 if not provided)
- So use the **time** [data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) which does not require a date
- Also, when converting from an unreliable data type, such as varchar, use `try_cast()` (or `try_convert()`) which will skip over values that cannot be converted by returning NULL ([see this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

For example:

```
declare @open as varchar(max) = '10:30:am'

select try_cast(Stuff(@open, 6, 1, ' ') as datetime) as open_time
```

| open_time |
| --- |
| 1900-01-01 10:30:00.000 |

```
declare @open as varchar(max) = '10:30:am'

select try_cast(Stuff(@open, 6, 1, ' ') as time) as open_time
```

| open_time |
| --- |
| 10:30:00.0000000 |

```
declare @open as varchar(max) = 'invaliod data 10:30:am'

select try_cast(Stuff(@open, 6, 1, ' ') as time) as open_time
```

| open_time |
| --- |
| *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7N8JiSE4)

Comment: I have updated to deal with the invalid time format